# Django full text search on multiple related field returning duplicate data

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

Consider I have below models.

```
class BoardStatus(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)

class Board(models.Model):
    board_id = models.SlugField(db_index=True, max_length=10, unique=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="board_creator", db_index=True)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, related_name="board_status",
     on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class BoardData(models.Model):
   board = models.ForeignKey(Board, related_name="board_data", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(db_index=True)
   host = noa_mail_hostname = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=100)
   address = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=200, blank=True)

Class BoardMailData(models.Model):
   board = models.OneToOneField(Board, related_name="board_mail_data", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   subject = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

For testing, I created 5 board objects with the same user and assigned the related tables to each board.

Let's consider in the created test data, one of the boards has a subject (related field) "Test Subject".

Now I want to do a full-text search on multiple related fields from the parent model i.e Board and I have the below query for that

```
filtered_qs_data = Board.objects.filter(status="some status")
filtered_qs_data.annotate(
    search=SearchVector(
              "creator__user_name", "board_mail_data__subject",
              "board_id", "creator__user_id", "board_data_host",
              "board_data__address" "board_data__ip"
            )).filter(search=SearchQuery("test subject", search_type='phrase')).distinct()
```

So Even though I have given distinct, the search value should return a single record from the DB, but it is returning single duplicate records. What I mean here is that it is returning the same "test subject" multiple times.

I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Please someone help me.

Comment: you mean it return multiple of the same "test subject" by object or just by a name column? because if you want to do distinct by column then you have to list it. If you don't put anything in distinct() it only if all column of 2 records all be the same, not single column

Comment: Yes, it is returning multiple of the same "test subject" and there is only a single record for "test subject". and I don't want anything distinct since it was returning multiple of the same object so I tried putting distinct after going through few StackOverflow question. I have no clue, even though there is a single record why it is returning that same object multiple times :(

Comment: i think the problem coming from your previous queryset, not from distinct(). Remove distinct from the queryset and see what it return

Comment: yes, I tried and it is the same. and the previous queryset is fine actually. the problem where it is occurring is. if I'm using multiple related objects from the same model then it is causing the problem. If there is only one related field from a model in  SearchVector (for example let's keep "board_mail_data__subject in the SearchVector) then it is only returning the single object.

Comment: But this will work fine if there are objects related to multiple users. In my project, there are different status. So based on the status first I will first get the queryset and then perform the search. so one of the status has multiple board objects with multiple users. there the full text is working fine actually. In another status there I have created board objects all related to a single user and when I perform full-text search on it, it is returning multiple of the same object. I have made the queryset changes in the question. Please have a look

Comment: Understood why the issue is happening. it's because in my table the search value is in multiple rows and probably that is why it is returning the duplicate records. but still, I have not found any solution. Any help on this would be highly appreciated